# Из-за чего появилась эта ошибка Call to undefined function session_start()?

Tags: php.ini, php

Здравствуйте!

Недавно перенес сайты на новенький сервер, а сегодня захожу на свой сайт и вижу такую картину:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_start() in /home/makan/data/www/gid28.ru/blocks/db.php on line 2**

session_start() - встроенная функция в PHP? ведь так? А с чем может быть связан такой затуп.

Надеюсь на ваши ответы, у меня порядка 30 сайтов встали колом....

Comment: Толко, что попробовал убрать session_start(); а сервер мне выдает: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/makan/data/www/gid28.ru/blocks/db.php on line 3

Comment: Хм. Может, с настройками на новом сервере что-то не так?

Comment: Понятно что с настройками, вот только с какими, и что изменилось, если почти месяц все было нормально, а теперь такая вот фиговина, кстати только что cделал "php как cgi" и ошибки пропали, а до этого в настройках было указано: php как модуль Apache

Answer (score 2):

Вы в принципе правы, только там не php был настроен не правильно, а проблема была в том что в Apche был указан неверный путь к php.ini и соответственно из-за этого и пошли все проблемы. А почему это произошло, до сих пор загадка, хостер молчит по этому поводу. Хотя спустя несколько часов все заработало... Всем спасибо за ответы!!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не с настройками а с тем, что модуль PHP скомпилирован без поддержки [сессий](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.installation.php).